# Koala and Omniauth-Facebook Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, devise

I've been able to add a facebook authentication to my app using the omniauth-facebook gem and devise. Everything is working perfectly. I have an oauth_token that I thought I could use to pass to Koala, but nothing I try from online tutorials seems to be working.

Most tutorials tell me to do something like this (http://udooz.net/blog/2011/02/facebook-app-using-rails-koala/), but I kept receiving a No Method error that directed me to this line:

graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(@facebook_cookies["access_token"])

Does anyone have any advice for a simple way to integrate Koala. I'm fairly new to rails and have made a lot of progress, but this is stumping me.

Comment: what is your ruby and rails version ?

Comment: Rails 4.0.4 & ruby 2.0.0p451

Comment: Then the link which you refer for integration of facebook API is for rails < 3 version and ruby 1.8.7, you should refer some other links to do this, if you wants then i can suggest you.

Comment: Yes that'd be extremely helpful - I haven't been able to find anything online

Comment: But i think that koala is still not support rails 4, there is an alternate solution for that is refer this link https://github.com/nov/fb_graph

Comment: Got it -  would you recommend any tutorials for fb_graph and rails 4?

Comment: The full implementation is given inside these link.